# Consider $T : \mathbb{R^7} \to \mathbb{R^7} $ linear transformation such that $\operatorname{Ker}(T) \cap T(\mathbb{R^7}) = ${0}$ $, show that ...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Consider $T : \mathbb{R^7} \to \mathbb{R^7} $ linear transformation such that  $\operatorname{Ker}(T) \cap T(\mathbb{R^7}) = ${0}$ $, show that $\mathbb{R^7}=\operatorname{Ker}(T) \bigoplus T(\mathbb{R^7} )$

I managed to show that if $\mathbb{R^7}=\operatorname{Ker}(T) + T(\mathbb{R^7} )$ then the sum is straightforward.

For the cases $y\in T(\mathbb{R^7})$  and $y\in\operatorname{Ker}(T)$ It is obvious.

but when $y$ doesn't meet the conditions above i couldn't work anymore, i tried to use the fact that the $ T ^ 2 $ function is bijection , but i couldn't complete anything

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\dim\ker T+\dim T(\Bbb R^7)=7$, by the rank-nullity theorem. So, since $\ker T\cap T(\Bbb R^7)=\{0\}$,$$\dim\bigl(\ker T+T(\Bbb R^7)\bigr)=\dim\ker T+\dim T(\Bbb R^7)=7,$$which means that $\ker T+T(\Bbb R^7)=\Bbb R^7$.